# How to change font substitutions in kpdf?

Tags: kde, fonts, pdf

I'm trying to read a pdf that was created with MSWord using Garamond and kpdf is substituting 'Deja Vu Sans'. But I've got Palladio! Where can I change it?

Comment: KPDF? I though it was replaced by Okular (same as KGhostView). I don’t even have it in the repositories of my distribution.

Comment: Cool. I'm ready to abandon it. I'll see what synaptic has to offer. Thanks.

Comment: Did Okular work for you?

Comment: I never found it in synaptic or apt-get. And later that computer died. And I'm on Windows now, so acrobat seems to have it covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very, very old question, but I'll add what I've learnt today to help out other google voyagers who end up here.

Specific font substitution is controlled by your ~/.fonts.conf which might be a link to ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf  (overall patterns are in /etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf)

In ~/.fonts.conf, within the  tags, add a section like

```
<match>                                                                                                              
    <test name="family"><string>FONT-TO-BE-REPLACED</string></test>                                                                  
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="strong">                                                                
      <string>REPLACE-WITH-THIS-FONT</string>                                                                                           
    </edit>                                                                                                            
  </match>
```

which in your case should be

```
<match>                                                                                                              
    <test name="family"><string>Garamond</string></test>                                                                  
    <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="strong">                                                                
      <string>Palladio</string>                                                                                           
    </edit>                                                                                                            
  </match>
```

That is how it *should be* done.